# Single Migration File for Initial Install?

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration

I've just started with with database migration files, and I'm setting up my initial install migration.

I have 134 tables in my PHP application.

I'd like to hear from those experienced in any programming language on whether I should create a single install migration, or split it up into 134 migration files, and the logic behind your recommendation.

This is for a MySQL database.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "initial install migration"?  And what is the size of your db? Are any tables significantly larger than others?  Are the target database and mysql config the same?

Comment: This will be an open source app that requires users to install it. 112KB gunzip compressed. There is one table that's much larger than the others. But for a schema migration there's no difference. I don't know what you mean by this `Are the target database and mysql config the same`.

Comment: Ahh, it sounds like you want to package the schema (with no data?) in some loadable format.  Probably the easiest way is to use mysqldump to dump the schema (create table statements, in sql) and have your installer read this .sql file into the database.  Does this sound like what you're asking for?

Comment: No. Thats what I'm moving away from. Sounds like you might not know what database migrations are. Thanks though.